# How to push value in variable using forEach function

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm having some trouble on displaying data from a JSON file like this one:

Currently `"checked": null`. I want to do `checked = true` in steps array using the `forEach` loop.

Here is my JSON data:

```
{
  "id": 4,
  "process": {
    "id": 24,
    "name": "test-1Process",
    "description": "Unknown",
    "steps": [
      {
        "id": 6,
        "title": "test1-process",
        "description": "test1 FDescriptin",
        "assetURL": "",
        "checked": null
      },
      {
        "id": 7,
        "title": "test1-step2",
        "description": "step2 description",
        "assetURL": "",
        "checked": null
      }
    ],
    "possibleEndStates": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "test2-tesp2"
      },
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "test2-tesp2"
      }
    ]
  },
  "user": {
    "id": 5,
    "firstname": "john",
    "surname": "edd",
    "email": "john@gmail.com ",
    "companyAdministrator ": false,
    "roles ": [
      {
        "id ": 2,
        "name ": "test1 - role ",
        "department ": {
          "id ": 2,
          "name ": "test1 - department ",
          "description": null,
          "company": {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "sd",
            "address": "default",
            "timezoneId": "default",
            "logoURL": "default"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Then push in a `steps` variable steps array.
Please, give me some suggestions.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please see [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: How does you generate your JSON data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Currently "checked": null I want to checked = true in steps array
>   using foreach loop

try

```
data.process.steps.forEach(function(val){
  val.checked = true;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this-

```
function changeKeyVal(element, index, array) {
   array[index]["checked"] = 'Value Renewed '+index;
  console.log(array[index]["checked"]);
}
data.process.steps.forEach(changeKeyVal);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also make use of Angular's in-built iterator since you are using Angular:

```
angular.forEach(data.process.steps, function(step) {
    step.checked = true;
});
```